# quotes in html different in view source vs. inspect

Tags: html, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to pull specific info from an html file & there are differences in what I see when I 'inspect' using dev tools vs. when I 'view source.'

In particular, one has the text:

```
<div class="pagination">
```

and the other has

```
<div class=pagination>
```

The html is fetched using this code:

```
var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(queryString).getContentText();
```

Although I have seen posts that talk about inspect vs. view source, they usually say that the correct one comes from 'inspect,' but in my case the fetched html does not have quotes for this particular file. This is only true in some cases ... other tags in the file do have quotes, even when there are no spaces in the class names. Why am I seeing what seems like inconsistent treatment of quotes in these files?

Comment: `View source` is the HTML as your browser received it. `Inspect` is the HTML as it's been parsed by your browser. So if "correct" means "as sent from the server", then no - `View source` is more "correct" there. But if "correct" means "parsed HTML", then `Inspect` is more "correct".

Answer (score 0):

`<div class=pagination>`
is not a valid HTML class syntax. When Chrome parses the HTML, it automatically 
try to "corrects" it for proper display by adding back the double quotes.

The code you see in inspector is the already corrected version for browser rendering.